# In Apps Script, when I use getCharts(), the charts come in the order of creation. Can I change the order somehow?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm copying charts from a big spreadsheet to docs. The charts for each sheet are the same but were created in different order. When I use getCharts(), they come in order of creation. Is there a way to change the order, perhaps top to bottom of the sheet?

I tried reordering in multiple ways and then using getCharts() but only order of creation matters.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Use [EmbeddedChart.getContainerInfo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getContainerInfo()) and the methods of the [ContainerInfo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/container-info) class to discover the anchor row and offset of each chart, then sort the charts array based on those values.